# Watin fails to return elements using find by text

Tags: find, contains, watin, substring

Im trying to return watin elements who's inner text contains a substring.
This works most of the time except when the inner text has certain characters. Im using the code below to search for an element with the following inner text:
<!-- end #account-area -->

```
ElementCollection ec = doc.Elements.Filter(Find.ByText(new Regex(str))); 

str = "<!-- end #account-area -->" ec[0] index out of range FAIL!
str = "account-area" ec[0] index out of range FAIL!
str = "account" ec[0] index out of range FAIL!
```

There seems to be special characters but why can't I find thee elemens using a substring with no special characters? How do I get the search to succeed?

Comment: What is the value of `str` when instantiating the `Regex` object?

Answer (score 0):

It seems str contained special characters like < and > which caused the comparison to fail. Also I am now searching the outer text of the document which does not contain special characters.